# Magento csv export and then to MySQL database

Tags: csv, export

I am trying to export the products to a csv file. System-Import/Export-Dataflow profiles- Export All Products, The data transfer method is set Local/Remote Server, the type is Local Server, Path is var/export. Then I go to Run Profile and click on Run Profile in Popup, the execution starts and everything has a green tick mark with the last row saying Saved successfully:"export_all_products.csv", then Finished profile execution. But when I go and enter the EC2 instance either through FileZilla or just SSH into it and look into the path for the file, there is no file. Could anyone help me out?

I am running a Magento EC2 instance on AWS (1.9.2.2-1 on Ubuntu 14.04.1)

Comment: Is the `var/export` directory writable? Try setting it to `chmod 777` to test

Comment: the export directory did not exist, I created it and used chmod 777 on it, run the export again, but no file was created.